# Problems building OpenCV with OpenCL support on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencl

I'm trying to build OpenCV 2.4.8 with support for OpenCL on Visual Studio 2010.

Everything seems to be working on CMake, except for the following warning message "

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDetectOpenCL.cmake:22 (message):
  Can't use OpenCL
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:471 (include)"
```

After this message, the output window shows that OpenCL support was not selected or will not be included in the build solution.

If I go on and command CMake to generate the MSVS solutuion, it works, and it's "buildable". But there will not be the OCL dll in the final build.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Every computer has its own cuda and opencl drivers. Maybe it queries the target machine to use its ocl. Maybe there is some selective installer options that checks target machine and uses the right ocl dll from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
CMakeLists.txt:471 (include)"
```

Looks like path to OpenCL includes are not found. Check that OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR, OPENCL_LIBRARY, OpenCL_DIR variables have correct values at Makefiles creating stage.